# Safe way to execute users JS code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Chrome extension, my goal to save user's code, which would be entered in some textarea  and executed later on user's PC. 
So this code will be stored in user's storage, and executed only on his PC. I am really looking onto eval, but i know this is a bad way to execute string code. So is there is a better ideas how to parse and execute users code?

BTW i can save this code via JS objects, so i can made them a functions, and save them as some variable(sorry for wrong semantics, I am new in javascript).

Comment: Depends on what that code should be able to do. If it's limited to internal processing and optionally displaying the result you can use a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandbox).

Comment: use the `Function` constructor rather than `eval`. That way, only the global scope is exposed to the code, not the current scope where you exec the code. And, you can easily inject/pass variables to the code, by defining them as arguments.

Comment: @Thomas Can you give a little bit more explanations? If a had users code  as string input. You suggest to save it which way? Something like this: `var x = new Function(user_string_code);` or something like this : `function f() { eval(user_string_code) ; } var x = f; `  Used this [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)